# Redux forms: correct way to populate form with data from top component with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm using redux forms (just trying to learn). And axios to get my `account` data and populate it into form.

I've made a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mzlrv1n988

From example: https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/initializefromstate/ everything seems to be clear and obvious. But it has nothing to deal with a real application: I refactored code a bit and i have top-level components for `add` && `edit` actions, who deal with server data and data from form. And I have a form component: it's goal is a form UI && validations.

How can I populate my form with data in top level component?

I mean this part of code in EditForm component:

```
  getAccount = () =>
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1").then(Account => {
      loadAccount(Account);
    });
```

also form component:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";
import { load as loadAccount } from "./account";
const data = {
  // used to populate "account" reducer when "Load" is clicked
  body: "testtest",
  title: "yep!"
};

let AccountForm = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, load, pristine, reset, submitting } = props;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => load(data)}>
          Load Account (example)
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>body</label>
        <div>
          <Field name="body" component="input" type="text" placeholder="body" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>title</label>
        <div>
          <Field
            name="title"
            component="input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="title"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting}>
          Submit
        </button>
        <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>
          Undo Changes
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

// Decorate with reduxForm(). It will read the initialValues prop provided by connect()
AccountForm = reduxForm({
  form: "initializeFromState" // a unique identifier for this form
})(AccountForm);

// You have to connect() to any reducers that you wish to connect to yourself
AccountForm = connect(
  state => ({
    initialValues: state.account.data // pull initial values from account reducer
  }),
  { load: loadAccount } // bind account loading action creator
)(AccountForm);

export default AccountForm;
```

If this can be done without using redux schema - it's even better, I do not need a huge part of logic here...

Also one small question: how to disable 'submit' button, while data is loading from the server?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your sandbox with the redux devtools you can see that the state is still empty after the axios call completes. This is because you are directly calling the reducer function instead of passing via a `dispatch`.

I edited the pen to illustrate the solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/o94p6ono3z

For the disable button you have to handle the usual redux process yourself: set a variable in the reducer before axios runs, unset it when axios is done. Then pass down that variable as you normally do in react/redux. Then set the button as disabled if that variable is true.

Meaning you do it like in a normal redux context no matter if you have a redux-form. What redux-form offers is the `submitting` variable that you can use to disable the button while the form is submitting.

Comment: how to be, if my model is different in form and update (like in post (create action) I send only ID & in edit form after /GET i gave a full model {:id, name:, etc} - how to populate such field?